# Comparing objects: using enhanced for loop

Tags: java, arrays, object, foreach, compare

I am iterating through an array of objects (different website types). But I want to be able to show which website has the highest amount of members. Initially my code shows the amount of members of each website, but my code isn't complete as im not sure how to compare the objects to see which has the highest amount of members. Current code:

```
public static void mostUsers(){

        for (Website w: websiteTypes){
            // check if the array index is not null
            if (w!=null){

                System.out.println(w.getType() + "has:" + w.getMembers());
                System.out.println(); // line break

                **//Code to compare amount of users on each site and display highest**
            } else {

                // no more records so quit loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a collection that allows nulls, because I would throw out the whole if/else there. You seem to misunderstand how the foreach loop works.

Comment: i thought that that meant stop iterating through the array if next space is null?

Comment: That's a bad idea, use a Collection, not an array. You're very new to Java aren't you? What is this program for, schoolwork?

Comment: yeah its for college, I simply would like to be able to compare the attributes of the different classes but not sure how to!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the maximum number of users while your iterating.

1. Initialize a variable called `maxWebsite` to `null` before your loop
2. Initialize an integer called `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` before your loop
3. While your iterating, test if `w.getMaxUsers()` is superior than the `max` value.
4. If it is, update accordingly the `maxWebsite` and `max` variables

Note : remove the else statement in your loop, you have to iterate all the elements of your array.

---

If you're using `Collections`, that could be simple using [`Collections.max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with a custom comparator :

```
List<Website> l = .......
l.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); //remove null elements from the list
Website maxWebsite = Collections.max(l, new Comparator<Website>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Website arg0, Website arg1) {
        return Integer.compare(arg0.getMaxUsers(), arg1.getMaxUsers());
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), or have Website extend [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Then, sort your collection of Websites using `sort`.  The websites with the most views will then be at the beginning of your collection.